# How to create a persistent unique index in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

*Disclaimer : I'm using mongoose for less than 48h.*

I have a model that looks like this :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Schema definition
var CategorySchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    url: { type: [String], index: true },
    extra: Array,
    frequency: Number,
    last_processed: Date
});

// Model definition
var Category = mongoose.model('categories', CategorySchema);
```

When my app launches, it has a method to automatically update the collection, using a js file structured like the following (js file which is not under my control):

```
var categories = {
    retailer: 'ret1',
    name: 'c1',
    url: 'url1',
    extra: ['tag1'],
    frequency: 2,
    last_processed: ''
}, {
    retailer: 'ret2',
    name: 'c2',
    url: 'url2',
    extra: ['tag2'],
    frequency: 2,
    last_processed: ''
}, 
  ........
];

module.exports = categories;
```

I create the records using a loop :

```
var Category = mongoose.model('categories');
for (var j = 0; j < categories.length; j++) {
    new Category(categories[j]).save();
}
```

---

My problem is the following :

When I launch my app the first time, db.categories.count()= 308 (as it should be). If I close the app and relaunch however, the count()=616, so it duplicates the records. I thought that using an index would avoid this behaviour, but apparently not. The documentation on indexes isn't clear to me, coming from a RDB background. I see in the debug that the index is created : `Mongoose: categories.ensureIndex({ url: 1 }) { safe: undefined, background: true }`

How can I create a persistent unique index on my collection so I NEVER have duplicates? After this simple startup routine, I will be writing on this table constantly, do I have to recreate an index after each write?

**Update after more research :**

I have no duplicates in the 308 urls I write and I start from an empty db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the index unique:

```
var CategorySchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    url: { 
        type: String, 
        index: {
            unique: true
        }
    },
    extra: Array,
    frequency: Number,
    last_processed: Date
});
```

Then, given you add a callback to the `save()`

```
for (var j = 0; j < categories.length; j++) {
    new Category(categories[j]).save(function(err, doc) {
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

You would see the following printed

```
{ [MongoError: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: test.categories.$url_1  dup key: { : "url2" }]
  name: 'MongoError',
  code: 11000,
  err: 'insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: test.categories.$url_1  dup key: { : "url2" }' }
```

You can use `findOneAndUpdate` which, given option `upsert: true`, would either create or update the object. If you don't want to update but just skip because a category exists using `save()` is probably good enough.

```
for (var j = 0; j < categories.length; j++) {
    Category.findOneAndUpdate(
        { url: categories[j].url },
        categories[j],
        { upsert: true },
        function(err, doc) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: yup, that works after correcting the typo in index (which I believe was copypasted from the docs). Thanks!